# How can we create a child tab inside a TabView in android?

Tags: android, tabs

**I am trying to create an android application that have a tab view in Home_Tab Activity.
it has 4 tabs. i want  to make some modification to the view, that is, when i click on the first tab it shows 4 child tab under that tab. how to create it ,
my code is given below**

```
         public class Home_tab extends TabActivity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_main);

    Resources ressources = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

    // Android tab
    Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, CoalActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost

      .newTabSpec("Android")

      .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_dis))
      .setContent(intentAndroid);




    // Apple tab
    Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, EnergyActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Apple")
      .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_foc))
      .setContent(intentApple);

    // Windows tab
    Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, PowerActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecWindows = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Windows")
      .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_nor))
      .setContent(intentWindows);

    // Blackberry tab
    Intent intentBerry = new Intent().setClass(this, TopNewsActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecBerry = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Berry")
      .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_sel))
      .setContent(intentBerry);

    // add all tabs 
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecWindows);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBerry);

    //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


              }


                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create class (CoalActivity) extends tabactivity again. and create new tab spec 
simple .............